# Spring Security how to redirect to login while calling a remoteFunction in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

When a user who is not logged in clicks on a link containing a remoteFunction like:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="${remoteFunction(
           controller: 'book',
           action: 'count',
        id: book.id,
        onSuccess: 'updateBookCount(data,textStatus);'
        )}">
        add count to book
        </a>
```

for an action:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
def count() { ... }
```

How can I redirect the user to the login page, if he is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution than what I currently have, but I ran into that in the past, where ajax calls don't call the normal redirect that spring security does when a session has expired. I assign contextPath to a javascript variable in main.gsp. This will log a user out 5 seconds before the session expires.

In main.gsp in the header I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contextPath = "${contextPath}";
    var maxTimeout = ${session.getMaxInactiveInterval()};
</script>
```

In my main.js I have:

```
if ( contextPath + "/" != window.location.pathname )
{
    setInterval('checkTimeOut()', 1000 );
}

function checkTimeOut()
{
    maxTimeout -= 1;
    if (maxTimeout <= 5)
        window.location = contextPath+"/logout"

}
```

Comment: Can you explain this more detailed? When a logged out user tries to access the above link to a secured page the JavaScript function updateBookCount(data,textStatus) will get an error I guess. How do I have to handle it?

Comment: They will be redirected to the logout page before their session times out. So that will never happen ( if they have scripts turned on ).

Comment: What I want is that the user will be redirected to the login page, if he is not logged in and tries to access a secured function over ajax. How can I do that?